# Hand-coded PDF file

Tags: pdf, output

My aim is to write directly the output of my program into a PDF file which is hand-coded. I found this nice tutorial and:

https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/0004.html

However, it is not possible to display extended ASCII characters/symbols, e.g., ASCII codes 179, ..., 218. I think that the issue arises within the third object (3 0 obj).

Note also that Courier New is used as a font type instead of Times-Roman. Moreover, when I close the PDF file Adobe Reader asks always if I want to save the changes?

To be more precise, the hand-coded PDF Looks like:

```
%PDF-1.7  
%Ñ€Ô  

1 0 obj  
<</Type/Catalog/Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>  
endobj  

2 0 obj  
<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1/MediaBox [0 0 937 280]>>  
endobj  

3 0 obj  
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/CourierNew>>>>>>/Contents 4 0 R>>  
endobj  

4 0 obj  
<< /Length 153 >>  
stream  
BT/F1 12 Tf 0 266 Td (Here, I want to display extended ASCII-Codes, e.g. code 205. bla bla bla) Tj ET  

endstream  
endobj  

xref  
0 5  
0000000000 65535 f  
0000000015 00000 n  
0000000074 00000 n  
0000000150 00000 n  
0000000283 00000 n  
trailer  
  <</Root 1 0 R/Size 5>>  
startxref  
338  
%%EOF
```

Has anybody a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Include your code, please - if possible, just a [mcve]. Note that "ASCII" does not define values above 127 - you probably should look up PDFEncoding or one of the other supported encodings (it's all in the official specifications), or provide your own.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Also, the fact that Adobe Reader asks to save the changes means your document is broken; probably (but not certainly) because you wrote incorrect values to the cross-reference table in your document.

Comment: hand-coded pdf provided

Comment: Pasting your PDF code here doesn't solve anything. PDF is a binary format, to know whether your line endings are correct, we'd need something to download. However, there are a number of error apparent already. Your catalog has two "Type" keys and the font you are using is NOT a base 14 font (Courier is one, Courier New is not), so you are obliged to have a font descriptor and a bunch of other stuff to define that font in your PDF file.